# Why would this not work? Latest Query for drop down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a drop down list and i want it to display only the latest data that was inputted in the database.

```
mysql_select_db($database_final, $final);
$query_LatestPO = "SELECT * FROM tbl_po ORDER BY id_po desc limit 1";
$LatestPO = mysql_query($query_LatestPO, $final) or die(mysql_error());
$row_LatestPO = mysql_fetch_assoc($LatestPO);
$totalRows_LatestPO = mysql_num_rows($LatestPO);
```

And this is the code for my Dynamic drop down list

```
<label>PO Number:</label>
      <select name="select3" id="select3">
        <?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_LatestPO['id_po']?>">
<?php echo $row_LatestPO['po_no']?></option><?php
} while ($row_LatestPO = mysql_fetch_assoc($LatestPO));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($LatestPO);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($LatestPO, 0);
  $row_LatestPO = mysql_fetch_assoc($LatestPO);
}
?>
      </select>
```

why does this not work? it displays all of the data from the table in the drop down list.

Comment: ah fml, i had 2 pages. one with the old code which was not updated and this one. i kept refreshing the other one. this code works well >.<

Comment: how many fields tbl_po contain?

Comment: it works well i was just stupid enough to refresh the other page and not the page that this code was saved